# Is there a way to format the outcome of a find function in Excel VBA as a number in Outlook?

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-word, formatting

I set up an Outlook template to send emails, containing information from an Excel database, using VBA.

I copy information needed in the email using a find function.

When I copy the outstanding balance, which is a digit, the formatting used in Excel is not copied to the email.

```vb
Sub Send_email_fromtemplate()
Dim edress As String
Dim cc1, cc2, cc3 As String
Dim group As String
Dim balance As String
Dim outlookapp As Object
Dim outlookmailitem As Object
Dim r As Long
Dim olInsp As Object
Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim oRng As Object

r = 3

Do While Sheet1.Cells(r, 1) <> ""
    Set outlookapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    'call your template
    Set outlookmailitem = outlookapp.CreateItemFromTemplate("G:\CCLAW & VIEWPOINT\Invoicing and reminding\Reminding project Noa\Reminding template final\official template final 1.oft")
    outlookmailitem.Display

    edress = Sheet1.Cells(r, 7)
    cc1 = Sheet1.Cells(r, 8)
    cc2 = Sheet1.Cells(r, 9)
    cc3 = Sheet1.Cells(r, 10)
    group = Sheet1.Cells(r, 4)
    balance = Sheet1.Cells(r, 6).Value
    With outlookmailitem
        .To = edress
        .cc = cc1 & ";" & cc2 & ";" & cc3
        .bcc = ""
        .Subject = "Invoice reminder " & group
        
        Set olInsp = .GetInspector
        Set wdDoc = olInsp.WordEditor
        Set oRng = wdDoc.Range
        With oRng.Find
            Do While .Execute(FindText:="{{Outstanding Balance}}")
                oRng.Text = balance
                Format = "#,###.##"
                Exit Do
            Loop
        End With
        Set xInspect = outlookmailitem.GetInspector
```

Using `Format = "#,###.##"` I hoped to update the formatting of the outstanding balance (so that e.g. 23153.5 is formatted as 23,153.50 in the email.

Comment: You're using the code `Format = "#,###.##"` but that isn't doing what you think, if you look in your 'Locals' window, you'll see a new string variable called `Format` with the type `Variant/String`. Check these docs for how to format a string, you'll want to use `formattedString = Format(stringToConvert, formatType)`

Comment: Try replacing `oRng.Text = balance` with `oRng.Text = Format(balance, "#,###.##")` and get rid of the `Format = "#,###.##"` line. If you always want the two decimal places to appear then replace `"#,###.##"` with `"#,###.00"`

Comment: Hi @JohnM , thanks a lot for this solve, obvious but I couldnt get to it :).. Thanks!

Comment: [Rubberduck](https://rubberduckvba.com) would have warned about the undeclared `Format` variable and the missing `Option Explicit` here, giving you a clue that something is off about that `Format` assignment.